# How to use group by and order by together on the same column in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am beginners to pyspark . i would like to know how to use both order by and group by together on the same column . my queries are below. my expectation is to show the user_state in alphabetical order . once that is donw , i will use pivot concept over it to segregate total male and female in each state . Thank you in advance . Appreciate for the help.

my code is now :
spark.sql("""select user_state , user_gender from users_vw where user_phone_numbers is not null order by user_state desc""").groupBy('user_state').pivot('user_gender').count().show()

i want to show the user_state as alphabetical sorted

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to show a list of user_state by state and gender:

```
state gender total
Utah  male    241
Utah  female  845 
...
```

Maybe this query can help:

```
SELECT 
  user_state,
  user_gender, # I don't know if its already a string or 1=male 0=female
  COUNT(user_gender) as total
FROM user_vw
WHERE user_phone_numbers is not null
GROUP BY user_-gender, user_state # group by gender, then by state
ORDER BY user_state
```